# Get depth of tree model data - Composite view - marionettejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, treetable

I was in an attempt of building Tree Table component using marionette compositeView.

Similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/peterkr/x5xt97m3/).

I have reference to [Derick's sample](http://jsfiddle.net/peterkr/25a04Lyr/1/) to build the tree menu using marionettejs.

```
// The recursive tree view
var TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#node-template",

    tagName: "ul",

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = this.model.nodes;
    }
});

// The tree's root: a simple collection view that renders 
// a recursive tree structure for each item in the collection
var TreeRoot = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    childView: TreeView
});
```

I was trying to use Table instead of UnOrder list, apply CSS class to each TR based on the depth of tree.

But here I unable to find a API to get depth of model while rendering it. Is there any way to get the depth during the recursive call?

Answer (score 0):

FYI: CompositeView is deprecated for removal

However to do the depth thing I think you could do something like this:

```
depth: 0,
childViewOptions: function(){
  return {
    depth: this.getOption('depth') + 1;
  };
}
```

In this example the default depth is 0, but subsequent children will have depth passed as an option.